# Hit detection in tilemaps

Tags: java, 2d, detection, hit

I'm working on a Mario game and am in need of assistance and suggestions on how to go about creating hit detection for a tilemap.

Currently, the player has the ability to walk/jump through the blocks.
I added in a fixed detection to the ground for now which I am hoping to replace with regular hit detection.

I understand that there are four sides to each block and the player. Only some blocks need hit detection and some things you might need to know is that the player stays at 300px(middle of screen) 98% of the time.

The only thing that moves is the map

The map is rendered from a .txt file and is rendered like so:

```
for(int y=0;y<map.length;y++) {
    for(int x=0;x<map[y].length;x++) {
        int index = map[y][x];
        int yOffset = 0;

        if(index>(tileSheet.getWidth() / Engine.TILE_WIDTH) -1) {
            yOffset++;
            index = index - (tileSheet.getWidth() / Engine.TILE_WIDTH);
        }

        g.drawImage(tileSheet, 
            ((x * Engine.TILE_WIDTH)*scale)+position,
            ((y * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT)*scale),
            (((x * Engine.TILE_WIDTH) + Engine.TILE_WIDTH )*scale)+position,
            (((y * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT) + Engine.TILE_HEIGHT)*scale),
            index * Engine.TILE_WIDTH,
            yOffset * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT,
            (index * Engine.TILE_WIDTH) + Engine.TILE_WIDTH,
            (yOffset * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT) + Engine.TILE_HEIGHT,
           null
       );
    }
}
//This code is actually longer(included file later on)
```

Colour hit detection is too slow and inconsistent for multi coloured tiles

Since the map is moving I suppose I need to move the hit detection boxes with it. As for selecting the boxes that it should detect might be difficult. Maybe it would be a better idea to make the code NOT hit detect certain tiles.

My attempts have ended in obfuscation of code. Can anyone suggest the easiest way to implement the hit detection? (keep in mind I have jumping).

The important codes are listed below:

Board.java(The panel where everything is drawn)

```
package EvilMario;                                                                                          //Include this class in the EvilMario game package

import java.awt.*;                                                                                          //Imported to allow use of Image
import java.awt.event.*;                                                                                    //Imported to allow use of ActionListener

import javax.swing.*;                                                                                       //Import swing

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {                                               //Class Board
private TileLayer l;                                                                                    //Instance of TileLayer class
private Menu m;                                                                                         //Instance of menu class
private Player p;                                                                                       //Instance of player class

    Timer time;                                                                                             //A timer

    public static enum STATE {MENU,GAME};                                                                   //The game states
    public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;                                                                 //Set the first state to menu

//END
//GLOBAL
//DECLARATIONS

    public Board() {
        l = TileLayer.FromFile("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/map.txt");                                              //Tile map data from .txt file
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput());                                                            //Listen for mouse input
        this.addKeyListener(new AL());                                                                      //Listen for key input

        p = new Player();                                                                                   //Start running Player class
        m = new Menu();                                                                                     //Start running Menu class

        setFocusable(true);                                                                                 //Allows movement

        time = new Timer(20,this);                                                                          //Timer set to update "this" class every 20 milliseconds(Approximately 50fps)
        time.start();                                                                                       //Actually start the timer
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.move();                                                                                           //Call the move method from the player class
        repaint();                                                                                          //Repaint
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {                                                                //Graphics method
        super.paintComponent(g);                                                                            //Super hero?
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;                                                                    //Cast 2D graphics

        if(State==STATE.GAME) {
            if(p.distanceTraveled<300)l.DrawLayer(g,0);else l.DrawLayer(g, -(p.distanceTraveled-300));      //Draw the tile map

            g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), 48, 48, null);                                  //Draw the player

            if(p.distanceTraveled==3488) System.out.println("You have won the game!");                      //Draw the end game screen
        } else {
            m.render(g);                                                                                    //Render the menu
        }
    }

    private class AL extends KeyAdapter {                                                                   //Action Listener extends key adapter
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                                                                //On key press
            p.keyPressed(e);                                                                                //Send whatever key was pressed  TO the keyPressed  method in the player class
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                                                               //On key release
            p.keyReleased(e);                                                                               //Send whatever key was released TO the keyReleased method in the player class
        }
    }
}
```

Player.java(player logic)

```
package EvilMario;                                                                                          //Include this class in the EvilMario game package
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {
    int x, dx, y, distanceTraveled;                                                                         //x coordinate,change in x coordinate,y coordinate,1st rep bg,2nd rep bg,dist traveled
    Image player;                                                                                           //The player variable
    ImageIcon walk_L_anim = new     ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/walk_L_anim.gif");
    ImageIcon walk_L_idle = new     ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/walk_L_idle.png");
    ImageIcon walk_R_anim = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/walk_R_anim.gif");
    ImageIcon walk_R_idle = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/walk_R_idle.png");

    ImageIcon jump_L_anim = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/jump_L_anim.gif");
    ImageIcon jump_L_idle = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/jump_L_idle.png");
    ImageIcon jump_R_anim = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/jump_R_anim.gif");
    ImageIcon jump_R_idle = new    ImageIcon("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/animatedMario/jump_R_idle.png");

    boolean holdingLeft = false;
    boolean holdingRight = false;
    static boolean jumping = false;
    static boolean falling = false;
    static int jumpingTime = 350;

    public Player() {
        player = walk_R_idle.getImage();                                                                    //Give the player the image
        x = 75;                                                                                             //The original x position of the player
        y = 277;                                                                                            //The original y position of the player
        distanceTraveled = 75;                                                                              //Original distance traveled
    }

    public void move() {
        if(x>=0 && x<=300) {                                                                                //If the player is within the moving area
            x = x+dx;                                                                                       //The x position is updated to become itself+the amount you moved
        }
        if(x<0)                                                                                             //If the player has reached he very left side of the screen(0px)
            x=0;                                                                                            //Move him up a pixel so he can move again
        if(x>300)                                                                                           //If the player has reached the center of the screen(300px)
            x=300;                                                                                          //Move him down a pixel so he can move again

        distanceTraveled=distanceTraveled+dx;                                                               //Calculate distanceTraveled

        if(distanceTraveled<0)                                                                              //Make sure distanceTraveled isn't a negative
            distanceTraveled=0;                                                                             //Make sure distanceTraveled isn't a negative
        if(distanceTraveled>=300)                                                                           //Keep player at center position once past 300 mario meters
            x=300;                                                                                          //Keep player at center position once past 300 mario meters

        if(holdingLeft && !holdingRight) {
            if(distanceTraveled<300)dx=-5; else dx=-4;

            if(jumping && !falling) {
                player = jump_L_anim.getImage();
                y-=8;
            } else {
                player = walk_L_anim.getImage();
                if(y<277)
                    y+=8;
            }
        } else if(holdingRight && !holdingLeft) {
            if(distanceTraveled<300)dx=5; else dx=4;

            if(jumping && !falling) {
                player = jump_R_anim.getImage();
                y-=8;
            } else {
                player = walk_R_anim.getImage();
                if(y<277)
                    y+=8;
            }
        } else if(!holdingRight && !holdingLeft) {
            dx = 0;

            if(jumping && !falling) {
                player = jump_R_anim.getImage();
                y-=8;
            } else {
                if(y<277)
                    y+=8;
            }
        }

        if(y==277) {
            falling = false;
        }

        System.out.println("LEFT: "+holdingLeft+"        JUMP: "+jumping+"       RIGHT: "+holdingRight+"       FALLING: "+falling+"     Y: "+y);
}

    public int   getX()     { return x;      }                                                              //This method will return the x.      Is used by other classes
    public int   getY()     { return y;      }                                                              //This method will return the y.      Is used by other classes
    public Image getImage() { return player; }                                                              //This method will return the player. Is used by other classes

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                                                                    //Called from the board class, the argument is whatever key was pressed
        int key = e.getKeyCode();                                                                           //The key originally sent from the board class

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !holdingLeft)
            holdingLeft = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !holdingRight)
            holdingRight = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !jumping && !falling)
            new Thread(new JumpThread(this)).start();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                                                                   //Called from the board class, the argument is whatever key was released
        int key = e.getKeyCode();                                                                           //The key originally sent from the board class

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {                                                                       //If the left or right key was released
            dx = 0;                                                                                         //Stop moving
            holdingLeft = false;
            player = walk_L_idle.getImage();
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
            holdingRight = false;
            player = walk_R_idle.getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

TileLayer.java (Rendering of the tile layer)(Probably most important part relating to the question)

```
package EvilMario;                                                                           //Include this class in the EvilMario game package

import java.awt.Graphics;                                                                    //

public class TileLayer {

    private int[][] map;                                                                     //2D array
    private BufferedImage tileSheet;                                                         //The tile sheet

    public TileLayer(int[][] existingMap) {                                                  //
        map = new int[existingMap.length][existingMap[0].length];                            //map initialized
        for(int y=0;y<map.length;y++) {                                                      //Loop through all boxes
            for(int x=0;x<map[y].length;y++) {                                               //Loop through all boxes
                map[y][x] = existingMap[y][x];                                               //Update the map
            }
        }
        tileSheet = LoadTileSheet("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/tilemap.gif");                 //Load the tilesheet
    }

    public TileLayer(int width, int height) {
        map = new int[height][width];
    }

    public static TileLayer FromFile(String fileName) {
        TileLayer layer = null;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempLayout = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String currentLine;

            while((currentLine = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                if(currentLine.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] values = currentLine.trim().split(" ");

                for(String string: values) {
                    if(!string.isEmpty()) {
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(string);
                        row.add(id);
                    }
                }
                tempLayout.add(row);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }

        int width = tempLayout.get(0).size();
        int height = tempLayout.size();

        layer = new TileLayer(width,height);
        for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {
            for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {
                layer.map[y][x] = tempLayout.get(y).get(x);
            }
        }
        layer.tileSheet = layer.LoadTileSheet("D:/ICS3U1/EvilMario/images/tilemap.gif");

        return layer;
    }

    public BufferedImage LoadTileSheet(String fileName) {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load image");
        }
        return img;
    }

    int scale = 2;

    public void DrawLayer(Graphics g, int position) {

        for(int y=0;y<map.length;y++) {
            for(int x=0;x<map[y].length;x++) {
                int index = map[y][x];
                int yOffset = 0;

                if(index>(tileSheet.getWidth() / Engine.TILE_WIDTH) -1) {
                    yOffset++;
                    index = index - (tileSheet.getWidth() / Engine.TILE_WIDTH);
                }

                g.drawImage(tileSheet, 
                        ((x * Engine.TILE_WIDTH)*scale)+position,
                        ((y * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT)*scale),

                        (((x * Engine.TILE_WIDTH) + Engine.TILE_WIDTH )*scale)+position,
                        (((y * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT) + Engine.TILE_HEIGHT)*scale),

                        index * Engine.TILE_WIDTH,
                        yOffset * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT,

                        (index * Engine.TILE_WIDTH) + Engine.TILE_WIDTH,
                        (yOffset * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT) + Engine.TILE_HEIGHT,
                        null
                );

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Engine.java (Not as important)(Simple variables for tile sizes)

```
package EvilMario;

public class Engine {
    public static final int TILE_WIDTH = 16;
    public static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 16;
}
```

If you need other pieces of code, just ask for them. I am not asking you to give me a specific answer to the question but simply a method that would work with my following code.

- A specific answer would be nice though :)

I also believe the answer to this question will be useful to others because this method was explained in a popular java 2d game tutorial video(They never showed hit detection).

Methods I tried:

Creating a new java file called HitDetectionLayer with the exact code in TileLayer.java that stored positions in arrays. It failed :(

Comment: This is **far** too much code for a Stack Overflow question.  Please boil this down to something succinct.

Comment: sorry, the only code to be looked at is the TileLayer.java, I included the others because people always yell at me for not knowing what variables do, etc.

Comment: @user3674464 Interesting...

Comment: Create a bool 2d array and give each element in that true or false variable depending on if the tile is "blocked" or not... Then create a method that returns a bool by checking if the current position + the predicted velocity is inside a "blocked" tile. If it is then don't move the player... I too used to code in java until I discovered unity3d and c#... So much less hastle :)

Comment: Why predict movements? Why not just check the past movement... and then move the player back before you redraw him?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not entirely sure what you are doing, if you throw up some images it would be more clear.

At any rate, 'hit detection' aka collision detection is a very complex topic, but it depends on what you want to do. If you want everything to be boxes or circles, then it is quite easy. If however you want things to rotate or you want collision for complex shapes it becomes extreme difficult.

Most games use circles or spheres for collision. You put the majority of your graphics (it may not fit perfectly either leaving part of your images in or out of the circle but that's life). Now lets say you have your mario sprite and one of those turtles. Well, you have circles around them both and once the circles touch you trigger your event.

The math for this is very easy because circles are by definition a perimeter around a constant length. Look at this:

[image: example1]
You probably already know this, and it may seem obvious, but if you think about it this is what a circle really is: a consistent length in every fathomable direction. The directions are measured in degrees and from there you move on to trigonometry but you don't need that. What you need is coordinance aka vectors. So look at this:

[image]
All you need to determine circle collision is the distance between the circles. No matter what angle the circles collide from it does not matter because the distances from the circle's centre are consistent all the way around. Even if the circles are different sizes, it doesn't matter, just account for the radii difference.

Too compute all of this, you would write a method like this:

```
public boolean testDistanceBetween( float radius1, float radius2, 
                                    float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2 ){

    double distanceBetween = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));

    if(distanceBetween < (radius1+radius2) ){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The moral of the story is that circles are just good that way. If you want to do rectangle collision you take the bottom-left and top right point and you test if other rectangles are in between those points. This should be pretty straight forward, each point is a vector, each rectangle has 4 points. If any of the 4 points of one rectangle are between points on the other rectangle, there is collision.

You can use this system to handle ground and walls also. For example, if ground is at Y=300, then if your sprite's y coordinance are == 300, you suspend your gravity.

The main thing I wanted to explain is that if you intend to have rotating rectangles or polygons and you want to detect collision on them... good luck. It can be done yes, but you should understand you are implementing complex physics, especially when/if you implement gravity.

So my answer is cautionary: there is NO easy way to detect collision of rotating rectangles or polygons. Circles and static rectangles are the limits. If you really want to do rotating rectangles/polygons get a physics engine. Box2d is pretty good and has a Java version Jbox2d.

Comment: In a Mario game, many things are cubes rather than circles: `distanceX = Math.abs(x1 - x2)`. Also consider doing something fast but inexact to rule out objects that are far away; then doing something slow but exact on the things that are close. Treat everything as circles until it gets close! Google "bounding boxes" as well.